# Muay Thai Jab vs Boxing Jab, Rear foot push forward

Tags: technique, boxing, muay-thai

I noticed in Muay Thai fundamentals, in Regular Jab they tell to push heel of right foot, to get the extra range power from Orthodox. In Book "Muay Thai Basics: Introductory Thai Boxing Techniques" and many resources incl Silva and others

https://youtu.be/85wRhMbdw6Q?t=74

https://youtu.be/Ejz9HJHQZag?t=31

In Regular boxing they do not recommend leaning forward on regular jab. "Leaning too far back or forward can tip the balance" as heard from many coaches.

https://blog.joinfightcamp.com/training/how-do-boxers-stay-balanced/

Is there a reason for the discrepancy? just curious, my theory is Boxing is much more jab punch heavy, so doing it continuously can cause balance issues. Any insight is good.

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that a different weight distribution (more on the front foot, achieved by "pushing" from the back foot) does necessarily involve leaning or getting out of balance? I think you overthink this here as the move can be much more subtle than that, yet it is important.

Comment: well think my question is why jab discrepancy general between boxing and Muay thai? not sure, just something I came across @PhilipKlöcking

Comment: My point is rather that I do not see the discrepancy in the first place: you do not have to lean into the jab if you push from the rear foot and turn your hips. It can be done much more subtle than that. Thus, what makes you think that the one implies the other?

Answer (score 3):

Whilst your question is justified (your reference recommends shifting the weight to the front foot), Philip Klöcking is right. You do not need to shift your weight onto the front foot to execute a strong jab.

Shifting your weight onto the front foot will allow you transfer more wight into your jab, but this necessitates forward commitment, which makes it harder for you to retreat back and out of range.

Jabbing as Klöcking describes, by pushing off the rear foot and turning your hips, enables knock-out power whilst maintaining much better defensive integrity.

Is this to say transferring your weight onto your front foot whilst jabbing is never appropriate? Not necessarily. If you have forced your opponent into a highly defensive attitude, you might deem the risk entailed by a forward weight distribution to be justified by the extra power and increased reach. You should remember however, that experienced boxers often like to draw forward commitment in order to make counters more effective. Mayweather is a master at this. And if he can do it, your opponent can. Why give away more than you have to?